# Silverlight and secure WCF Service problem

Tags: wcf, security, silverlight-4.0

I have a WCF service project defined in my Silverlight solution. The solution consists of three projects.

- MySilverLightApplication [the
  Silverlight app]
- MySilverLightApplication.Web [the web
  project that hosts it]
- MyWCFService

I want to establish a secure connection between the Silverlight application and the WCF service so I turned on `wsHttpBinding` on the service side by editing the service project's web.config file like so:

```
<services>
    <service name="ExternalWcfService.extService"
        behaviorConfiguration="ExternalWCF">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            contract="ExternalWcfService.IextService"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
            contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

When I add a reference to this service in the SL client I get NO entry made in the `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig` file in the Silverlight app. Why is this so? And then when I run the application I get an error like so:

> Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references contract
>   'ExternalWCFService.IextService' in
>   the ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no endpoint
>   element matching this contract could
>   be found in the client element.

I have the `silverlight.config` file in the Silverlight root folder. Why is the endpoint not getting created in the SL project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Apparently Silverlight cannot consume a service configured with wsHttpBinding. It needs to be BasicHttpBinding only! I changed the binding to basic and my endpoint was added to the ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file when I updated my reference.

Strange!!! why doesnt Silverlight support encoding over the wire?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to manually copy the generated file into the Silverlight project. It should be in your MyWCFService project. I remember having to do this before but it wasn't for the same thing, but it was for a standard webservice endpoint.